# Which versions of bible are Bible in Basic English and Union Version?

Tags: bible

Does [Bible in Basic English](https://www.o-bible.com/bbe.html) correspond to some popular version of bibles? Is it dynamic like NLT?

Same questions about [Union Version (和合本)](https://www.o-bible.com/gb/hgb.html)?

Thanks.

Comment: Tim, I think you need to provide more information about research you have already done and not expect us to click on to Chinese links.  Please edit your question and be more specific.